# How to extract stored procedure DDL using FireDAC

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac, fibplus

I am in the process of changing from FIBPlus to FireDAC, and most functionality I need is in FireDAC, I'm just battling to find the FIBPlus equivalent of TpFIBDBSchemaExtract and TpFIBScripter for extracting the stored procedures as DDL.

Does FireDAC have a way of extracting the stored procedure DDL from a database?

For example, would look like:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROC RETURNS (aParam INTEGER) AS
BEGIN
  aParam = 10;
END^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FireDAC does not support (unified) fetching DDL definitions of stored procedures (at this time). So, you'll need to fetch that DDL from the [**RDB$PROCEDURES**](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx04-procedures.html) table, **RDB$PROCEDURE_SOURCE** column by yourself. For example (not ideally designed as a connection object helper though):

```
uses
  FireDAC.Stan.Util;

type
  TFDConnectionHelper = class helper for TFDConnection
  public
    function GetStoredProcCode(const AName: string): string;
  end;

implementation

{ TFDConnectionHelper }

function TFDConnectionHelper.GetStoredProcCode(const AName: string): string;
var
  Table: TFDDatSTable;
  Command: IFDPhysCommand;
begin
  CheckActive;
  if RDBMSKind <> TFDRDBMSKinds.Firebird then
    raise ENotSupportedException.Create('This feature is supported only for Firebird');

  Result := '';
  ConnectionIntf.CreateCommand(Command);

  Command.CommandText := 'SELECT RDB$PROCEDURE_SOURCE FROM RDB$PROCEDURES WHERE RDB$PROCEDURE_NAME = :Name';
  Command.Params[0].DataType := ftString;
  Command.Params[0].Size := 31;
  Command.Params[0].AsString := UpperCase(AName);

  Table := TFDDatSTable.Create;
  try
    Command.Define(Table);
    Command.Open;
    Command.Fetch(Table);

    if Table.Rows.Count > 0 then
      Result := Table.Rows[0].GetData(0);
  finally
    FDFree(Table);
  end;
end;
```

Usage then (when you're connected to Firebird DBMS):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := FDConnection1.GetStoredProcCode('MyProcedure');
  ...
end;
```

Comment: This column however can be cleared after SP creation by the database developer.

Comment: @Arioch, then you fool FIBPlus as well because it internally queries `RDB$PROCEDURE_SOURCE`.